View not updating despite data updating with ObservableObject and EnvironmentObject
I have a pretty basic app that I've put together. Below I've given literally all of my code.
First of all, here is my main App struct where I use MyViewModel as the single source of truth:
@main
struct TestApp: App {
    @StateObject var myViewModel = MyViewModel()
    
    var body: some Scene {
        WindowGroup {
            HomeView()
                .environmentObject(myViewModel)
        }
    }
}

MyViewModel is very basic:
class MyViewModel: ObservableObject {
    @Published var users: [User] = []
    
    func getUsers() {
        self.users = [
            User(id: 1, username: "Username", messages: [
                Message(id: 1, userId: 1, date: "2024-04-16", message: "First comment"),
                Message(id: 2, userId: 1, date: "2024-04-17", message: "Second comment"),
                Message(id: 3, userId: 1, date: "2024-04-18", message: "Third comment"),
            ])
        ]
    }
    
    func changeDate(userId: Int, messageId: Int, date: String) {
        if let userIndex = users.firstIndex(where: { $0.messages.contains(where: { $0.id == messageId }) }) {
            if let messageIndex = users[userIndex].messages.firstIndex(where: { $0.id == messageId }) {
                users[userIndex].messages[messageIndex][keyPath: \.date] = date
            }
        }
    }
}

As you see, I keep a list of Users. I also have a function changeDate() which I'll talk about later.
Then I have the HomeView. Here I show a list of all the Users:
struct HomeView: View {
    @EnvironmentObject var myViewModel: MyViewModel

    var body: some View {
        NavigationStack {
            VStack {
                ForEach(myViewModel.users, id: \.id) { user in
                    UserItem(user: user)
                }
            }
        }
        .task {
            myViewModel.getUsers()
        }
    }
}

And here is what UserItem looks like:
struct UserItem: View {
    var user: User
    
    var body: some View {
        NavigationLink(destination: UserPageView(user: user)) {
            Text(user.username)
        }
    }
}

On tap, it takes the user to the UserPageView, where I show a list of the user's messages, grouped by day:
struct UserPageView: View {
    var user: User
    
    var body: some View {
        ForEach(user.groupedMessagesByDay) { day in
            VStack {
                Text(day.date)
                
                ForEach(day.messages, id: \.id) { message in
                    MessageView(message: message)
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

Here is the User model, where you can see how I group their messages by day:
struct User: Identifiable {
    var id: Int
    var username: String
    var messages: [Message] {
        didSet {
            groupedMessagesByDay = getGroupedMessages()
        }
    }
    var groupedMessagesByDay: [Day] = []
    
    init(id: Int, username: String, messages: [Message]) {
        self.id = id
        self.username = username
        self.messages = messages
        self.groupedMessagesByDay = getGroupedMessages()
    }
    
    func getGroupedMessages() -> [Day] {
        var messagesByDay: [String: [Message]] = [:]
                    
        for message in messages {
            let date = message.date
            if var messagesOnDate = messagesByDay[date] {
                messagesOnDate.append(message)
                messagesByDay[date] = messagesOnDate
            } else {
                messagesByDay[date] = [message]
            }
        }
        
        var days: [Day] = []
        for (date, messages) in messagesByDay {
            let day = Day(date: date, messages: messages)
            days.append(day)
        }
        
        days.sort { $0.date < $1.date }
        
        return days
    }
    
}

Here is what Message looks like:
struct Message: Identifiable {
    let id: Int
    let userId: Int
    var date: String
    var message: String

    init(id: Int, userId: Int, date: String, message: String) {
        self.id = id
        self.userId = userId
        self.date = date
        self.message = message
    }
}

And here is what Day looks like:
struct Day: Identifiable {
    var id = UUID()
    var date: String
    var messages: [Message]
}

Each message displayed shows this:
struct MessageView: View {
    var message: Message
    
    var body: some View {
        NavigationLink(destination: MessagePageView(message: message)) {
            Text("Show message page for id: \(message.id)")
        }
    }
}

When a message is tapped, I take them to MessagePageView:
struct MessagePageView: View {
    @EnvironmentObject var myViewModel: MyViewModel
    
    var message: Message
    
    var body: some View {
        // Show the current message date
        Text(message.date)
        
        // Tap button to change date to "2024-05-01"
        Button(action: {
            myViewModel.changeDate(userId: message.userId, messageId: message.id, date: "2024-05-01")
        }, label: {
            Text("Change message")
        })
    }
}

Here is where I'm stuck.
I expected that, on tap of the Button, the message date would be updated to "2024-05-01" and that the date displayed on the page (Text(message.date)) would update, but it doesn't.
I can confirm that the data is updating based on my breakpoints, but the UI is not.
What am I doing wrong with my implementation of EnvironmentObject? What am I not understanding?
Thanks

User should not be a class. If you want to use a class, you need @Observable. What iOS version are you supporting?

Try making User a struct, and
in your HomeView you should have
@EnvironmentObject var myViewModel: MyViewModel.
Have a look at this link Managing model data in your app, for how to manage data in your app.
As mentioned if targeting ios17+, you could use @Observable, see this link
Managing model data in your app.

I made User a struct and added @EnvironmentObject var myViewModel: MyViewModel to HomeView. The date is updating on MessagePageView, but not on UserPageView. Why would this be happening?

I suggest you
restructure your code. Currently you have func getGroupedMessages() -> [Day] etc...
that returns different Day that contains another copy of [Messages],
that the User already have in var messages: [Message].
Have one data source of truth for your [Message], then use sorting to
group them. Making duplicates in your Day is not the way to go.
Message already has a date.

OK, now I'm extremely confused. If I keep the Message model as a struct, the child view UI updates (MessagePageView), but not the parent view (UserPageView). If I change Message to a class and  make it an ObservableObject, the child view does NOT update, but the parent view DOES. How can I make sure BOTH get updated??

@workingdogsupportUkraine The issue is that I want to show messages grouped by day in my UI, which is why I have getGroupedMessages(), and I use the key of that array to display the date above the messages: https://i.imgur.com/ox1tOy4.png. Then in the future, I want to show UI for all messages that have no date set, so a different dataset for that as well.

Try adding objectWillChange.send() at the end of the changeData function. The dictionary has a copy of the message, that message has no connection with the original.

@loremipsum Unfortunately, it updated in the child view, but not in the parent view.

try putting groupedMessagesByDay inside UserPageView also add Hashable and Equatable (default implementations, DON'T implement custom ones) to all the models

Actually change var groupedMessagesByDay: [Day] to var groupedMessagesByDay: [Day]{ getGroupedMessages()} you are breaking the connections twice there.

what you've got there is a model store not a view model. In SwiftUI the View structs are the view model.

updated my answer with the full working code. See also Apple recommendations, Monitoring data for how to manage data in your app. Use your class MyViewModel: ObservableObject as described in the official docs.

If you still want to use your current setup, then you could try
this approach using  @State var message: Message as shown in the example code.
This will change the myViewModel and the local display.
Simply updating the var message: Message will not update the View, you need to use @State ...
struct MessagePageView: View {
    @EnvironmentObject var myViewModel: MyViewModel
    @State var message: Message  // <-- here
  
    var body: some View {
        // Show the current message date
        Text(message.date)  
        
        // Tap button to change date to "2024-05-01"
        Button(action: {
            // for testing
            let newDate = "2024-05-01 " + String(UUID().uuidString.prefix(7))
            message.date = newDate // <-- here
            myViewModel.changeDate(userId: message.userId, messageId: message.id, date: newDate)
        }, label: {
            Text("Change message")
        })
    }
}

EDIT-1:
Here is my code using your current setup, that updates both the MessagePageView
and the parent View. On MacOS 14.4, using Xcode 15.3, tested on real ios 17 devices (not Previews), macCatalyst and MacOS. Let us know if this code does not work for you.
@main
struct TestApp: App {
    @StateObject private var myViewModel = MyViewModel()
    
    var body: some Scene {
        WindowGroup {
            HomeView()
                .environmentObject(myViewModel)
        }
    }
}

struct HomeView: View {
    @EnvironmentObject var myViewModel: MyViewModel
    
    var body: some View {
        NavigationStack {
            VStack {
                ForEach(myViewModel.users) { user in
                    UserItem(user: user)
                }
            }
        }
        .task {
            myViewModel.getUsers()
        }
    }
}

class MyViewModel: ObservableObject {
    @Published var users: [User] = []
    
    func getUsers() {
        self.users = [
            User(id: 1, username: "Username", messages: [
                Message(id: 1, userId: 1, date: "2024-04-16", message: "First comment"),
                Message(id: 2, userId: 1, date: "2024-04-17", message: "Second comment"),
                Message(id: 3, userId: 1, date: "2024-04-18", message: "Third comment"),
            ])
        ]
    }
    
    func changeDate(userId: Int, messageId: Int, date: String) {
        if let userIndex = users.firstIndex(where: { $0.messages.contains(where: { $0.id == messageId }) }) {
            if let messageIndex = users[userIndex].messages.firstIndex(where: { $0.id == messageId }) {
                users[userIndex].messages[messageIndex][keyPath: \.date] = date
            }
        }
    }
}

struct UserItem: View {
    var user: User
    
    var body: some View {
        NavigationLink(destination: UserPageView(user: user)) {
            Text(user.username)
        }
    }
}

struct UserPageView: View {
    var user: User
    
    var body: some View {
        ForEach(user.groupedMessagesByDay) { day in
            VStack {
                Text(day.date)
                
                ForEach(day.messages) { message in
                    MessageView(message: message)
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

struct User: Identifiable { // <-- here
    var id: Int
    var username: String
    var messages: [Message] {
        didSet {
            groupedMessagesByDay = getGroupedMessages()
        }
    }
    var groupedMessagesByDay: [Day] = []
    
    init(id: Int, username: String, messages: [Message]) {
        self.id = id
        self.username = username
        self.messages = messages
        self.groupedMessagesByDay = getGroupedMessages()
    }
    
    func getGroupedMessages() -> [Day] {
        var messagesByDay: [String: [Message]] = [:]
        
        for message in messages {
            let date = message.date
            if var messagesOnDate = messagesByDay[date] {
                messagesOnDate.append(message)
                messagesByDay[date] = messagesOnDate
            } else {
                messagesByDay[date] = [message]
            }
        }
        
        var days: [Day] = []
        for (date, messages) in messagesByDay {
            let day = Day(date: date, messages: messages)
            days.append(day)
        }
        
        days.sort { $0.date < $1.date }
        
        return days
    }
    
}

struct Day: Identifiable {
    var id = UUID()
    var date: String
    var messages: [Message]
}

struct MessageView: View {
    var message: Message
    
    var body: some View {
        NavigationLink(destination: MessagePageView(message: message)) {
            Text("Show message page for id: \(message.id)")
        }
    }
}

struct MessagePageView: View {
    @EnvironmentObject var myViewModel: MyViewModel
    var message: Message 
    
    @State private var msg: Message?  // <-- here
    
    var body: some View {
        // Show the current message date
        Text(msg?.date ?? "")  // <-- here
        
        // Tap button to change date to "2024-05-01"
        Button(action: {
            // for testing
            let newDate = "2024-05-01 " + String(UUID().uuidString.prefix(7))
            msg?.date = newDate // <-- here
            myViewModel.changeDate(userId: message.userId, messageId: message.id, date: newDate)
        }, label: {
            Text("Change message")
        })
        .onAppear {
            msg = message // <-- here
        }
    }
}

struct Message: Identifiable {
    let id: Int
    let userId: Int
    var date: String
    let message: String
}


State should always be private per the documentation

Unfortunately, the child view UI updates (MessagePageView), but not the parent view (UserPageView).

updated my answer with the full code I use for my tests. The code works for me, both the MessagePageView and the parent View are updated when the Button is pressed and the date is changed.
